# Can I generate a page with only headers and footers?

Tags: header-footer

I tried generating a page with only headers and footers and I keep getting an error I can't even understand.

The error is too verbose to attach but here's my code.

It works perfectly if i attach even a small section of code.

I just need to be sure that I can never generate a header and footer alone for future reference.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{geometry}%
\geometry{head=120pt,foot=40pt,margin=0.5in,bottom=0.6in,includeheadfoot=True}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{ragged2e}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{tabularx}%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%
%
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
\fancyhead{%
}%
\fancyfoot{%
}%
\fancyhead[L]{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=120px]{fuoye_logo.png}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
\fancyhead[R]{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth}%
\flushright%
\begin{Large}%
\textbf{Bank Account Statement}%
\end{Large}%
\linebreak%
\begin{large}%
\textbf{Date}%
\end{large}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
\fancyfoot[C]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X X}%
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textcolor{blue}{%
Important message please read%
}}\\%
\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
\hline%
&&&\\%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}%
960 {-} 22nd street east%
\newline%
%
Saskatoon, SK%
\end{minipage}&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}%
960 {-} 22nd street east%
\newline%
%
Saskatoon, SK%
\end{minipage}&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}%
960 {-} 22nd street east%
\newline%
%
Saskatoon, SK%
\end{minipage}&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}%
\flushright%
1000%
\linebreak%
Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}%
\end{minipage}\\%
\end{tabularx}%
}%
}%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\pagestyle{firstpage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There should be at least something on the page, otherwise TeX outputs no PDF (which will be maybe the warning you get). You can put `\null` on the page which renders nothing.

Comment: @JasperHabicht `px` is a valid unit with PDFLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, but not with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Much appreciated!